# How to write scope with belongs_to object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, scopes

I have the following models

*Models*

```
Job
  belongs_to :company
Company
  has_many :jobs
```

Right now I select all the `Jobs`  which have an accepted `Company` using the following method:

```
def self.with_accepted_company
  Job.all.reject {|job| job.company.state != "accepted" }
end
```

But I would like to use scope for that and use it with other scopes. Is this possible to write that scope in the `Job` model?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would do something like this (from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
class Job
  scope :accepted_with_active_company, ->() {
    joins(:company).where('companies.state' => "accepted") 
  }
end
```

Comment: I get an error using this scope 

```>> Job.accepted_with_active_company.inspect
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'companies' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /Users/rege/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@ckdatabase/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:112:in `build'
```

Comment: The error message tells you that you don't have an association named :companies. The original code assumes it was a `has_many` relation but in face it is `belongs_to` what you should do is have joins(:company) instead of joins(:companies). I have edited the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative syntax for the where clause:

```
class Job
  scope :accepted_with_active_company, ->() {
    joins(:company).where(companies: { state: 'accepted' }) 
  }
end
```