# Rails belongs_to has_many with db conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship, rails-activerecord

I have two models, let's say:

```
Post:
  blog_id: integer
  external_id: integer

Comment:
  blog_id: integer
  external_reference_id: integer
```

And have some items in my db:

```
Post.create external_id: 10, title: "Test 1", blog_id: 1
Post.create external_id: 10, title: "Test 2", blog_id: 2
Post.create external_id: 10, title: "Test 3", blog_id: 3

Comment.create external_reference_id: 10, title: "Comment 1.1", blog_id: 1
Comment.create external_reference_id: 10, title: "Comment 1.2", blog_id: 1

Comment.create external_reference_id: 10, title: "Comment 2.1", blog_id: 2
Comment.create external_reference_id: 10, title: "Comment 2.2", blog_id: 2
```

I need to relate post and comments using the `external_` reference, that is:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, foreign_key: :external_reference_id, primary_key: :external_id
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :external_reference_id, primary_key: :external_id
end
```

What I need is to "scope" the relation between the two on blog_id to be the same.

By this I mean a scenario where I have different blogs on different server/databases, and I'm collecting all the data in a master server. I cannot preserve the original ID, so I store the id as external_id. This means that the Post with `external_id: 1` and `blog_id: 4` will have all the Comments that have `external_reference_id: 1` and `blog_id: 4`.

I may have lot of comments with the same `external_id` but only that with the same blog_id really matches.

Surfing the internet, I found a couple of hint, the most popular opinions are something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> (object){ where("comments.blog_id = #{object.blog_id}") }, foreign_key: :external_reference_id, primary_key: :external_id
end
```

This solution correctly generate the query when doing `Post.first.comments`:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."external_reference_id" = ? AND (comments.blog_id = 1)  [["external_reference_id", 10]]

But it fails miserably when trying something more esoteric like `Post.joins(:comments).count` giving:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `blog_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation
```

So far my solution is then:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> (object){ where(object.respond_to?(:blog_id) ? "comments.blog_id = #{object.blog_id}" : 'comments.blog_id = posts.blog_id') }, foreign_key: :external_reference_id, primary_key: :external_id
end
```

Which works fine, but looks a little bit over-complicated in my opinion. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain more about `What I need is to "scope" the relation between the two on blog_id to be the same.`.  The same as what, for example?

Comment: What I mean is that a comment belongs to a post only if they match the blog_id field. Assume I have different blogs in separate servers/database and I'm importing all the data in my master server. I cannot preserve ids, so I save the original id in external_id for posts, and the original post_id in external_reference_id for contents. So the post for a comment is the post having external_id matching the external_reference_id and having the same blog_id. I know it may not be the better implementation but that's my data now.

Comment: Ah, you should add that to the OP as it's useful info.

Comment: I had the same issue and found the response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893429/how-to-write-scope-with-belongs-to-object

Answer (score 0):

You can add :conditions to has_many and belongs_to, eg

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: :external_reference_id, primary_key: :external_id, :conditions => ["comments.blog_id = posts.blog_id"]
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :external_reference_id, primary_key: :external_id, :conditions => ["comments.blog_id = posts.blog_id"]
end
```

I've not tested this but give it a go.

Comment: That's one of the things I've tried, but it does not work when relations are called: `Comment.first.post` makes a query only in post table, so trying to have `comments.blog_id = posts.blog_id` breaks the query: `SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."external_id" = ? AND (comments.blog_id = posts.blog_id) ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["external_id", 10]]`